# Adding the values of select input menus

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I could use a little help as I have little JavaScript knowledge.

I am trying to use multiple select menus and in real time add the values off the selected items and subtract from a  fixed number.

```
<form>
<section id="extra-features">
<select name="450_1" id="450_1" class="form-control" onchange="updateTotals()" >
<option selected="selected"></option>
<option value="larry,13">larry</option>
<option value="dex,12">dex</option>
<option value="ryder,18">ryder</option>
</select>
<select name="450_2" id="450_2" class="form-control" onchange="updateTotals()">
<option selected="selected"></option>
<option value="bob,4">bob</option>
<option value="jim,6">jim</option>
<option value="stew,7">stew</option>
</select>
</section>   
</form>
<p id="total"></p>
<p id="balance"></p>
```

Here Is my javascript

```
function updateTotals() {
var inputs = document.getElementById('extra-features').getElementsByTagName('select');

var sum = 0;
var bsum = 2000000;
for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].change) {
        sum += parseInt(inputs[i].getAttribute('value').split(",")[1]);
        bsum -= parseInt(inputs[i].getAttribute('value').split(",")[1]);
    }
}

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = bsum;
}

var section = document.getElementById('extra-features');
var inputs = section.getElementsByTagName('select');

for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++) {
inputs[i].addEventListener('change', updateTotals);
}
```

Here is my fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nb5b48z/2/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Its not working. My question is what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you binding the change event on the selects twice?

Comment: do you mean getElementById & getElementsByTagName if so cause i was trying different things

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7nb5b48z/5/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few issues:

First, you don't need to add the change listeners twice (in HTML and then in JavaScript).

Second, `inputs[i].change` is undefined, so your `sum` and `bsum` would never get changed. I'm not sure what that was trying to accomplish, but it is unnecessary. Instead of it, I put `if(inputs[i].value)` to check if a value has been selected yet. If you don't have this, and one of the selects has no value, you will get `NaN` as a result when you calculate `sum` and `bsum`.

Third, `getAttribute('value')` returns `null`. You can just get the value using `.value`.

```
function updateTotals() {
    var inputs = document.getElementById('extra-features').getElementsByTagName('select');

    var sum = 0;
    var bsum = 2000000;
    for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].value) {
            sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value.split(",")[1]);
            bsum -= parseInt(inputs[i].value.split(",")[1]);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
    document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = bsum;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k1mkdsx6/